# Checking macro definition with scons?

Tags: libraries, scons

I am checking for the presence of VTK with `Conftest.CheckHeader`.
Specifically, I check for `<vtkVersion.h>` being found. Now I would like to see what the version of VTK actually is, which could be done by inspecting `VTK_MAJOR_VERSION` and `VTK_MINOR_VERSION`. Is there a clean way to do that in SCons, e.g. somehow returning preprocessed source which would simply contain `VTK_MAJOR_VERSION VTK_MINOR_VERSION` and return `6 0`?

Comment: Currently there is nothing implemented to do what you're asking. Perhaps an email sent to the scons user's list would be helpful: scons-users@scons.org

Comment: Generally the configure tests work by compiling, linking, or running an auto generated program and looking at the results thereof to determine the status of each particular check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might try (from  [scons manpage](http://scons.org/doc/production/HTML/scons-man.html))

> CheckContext.TryRun(self, text, extension)
>
> Checks, if a file with the specified extension (e.g. '.c') containing text can be compiled using the environment's Program
>   builder. On success, the program is run. If the program executes
>   successfully (that is, its return status is 0), a tuple (1, outputStr)
>   is returned, where outputStr is the standard output of the program. If
>   the program fails execution (its return status is non-zero), then (0,
>   '') is returned.